# Exception when allocating an array, no exception when allocating it as a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to use the following dynamically-allocated array:

```
long currsize = 524288;
int *insertedEdges = new int[currsize*currsize];
```

but when I run this code, my program terminates with an error message saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
```

However, if I convert the same array to a 2D array, and allocate  the same amount of memory, using `new` in a loop, the memory gets allocated:

```
printf("ALLOCATIONS START \n");
int **insertedEdges = new int*[currsize];
for(int i = 0; i < currsize; i++) {
    insertedEdges[i] = new int[currsize];
}
```

How can I allocate memory for my 1D array without triggering the exception?

Comment: Presumably your heap is fragmented by previous allocations and deallocations. Then allocating one huge block would fail (because there's no one contigous block), but allocating many small blocks can fit in the gaps.

Comment: currsize is 524288. I know its huge, but a similar amount of memory gets allocated in the case of a 2-d array using new nested loops. Also, I need a workaround specifically for the case of 1-d arrays (if possible).

Comment: @AbhivanditVerma Please do as advised and [edit] your question to present a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Narrow your actual code down as much as possible to reproduce just that problem.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ is this ok?

Comment: @  πάντα ῥεῖ which part is not getting compiled. And i have read the article and made the necessary changes.

Comment: The point is, copying and pasting into a file and hitting compile won't work. A MCVE has at least an `int main`, all necessary #includes, etc.

Comment: @AbhivanditVerma: No, it's not ok yet. Without a fully-compilable example we can't be sure if there aren't other factors that cause the behavior you're seeing. Full program please - you're almost there...

Comment: Are you on a 32 or 64-bit system?  If you're on a 32-bit system, then `524288*524288` is going to cause problems.

Comment: i am using a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first snippet, the code asks for **one big block** of memory, with size 524288*524288*sizeof(int). In the second one, the code asks for one block of size 524288*sizeof(int*) and 524288 blocks of size 524288*sizeof(int).

Smaller blocks are generally easier, from a memory management perspective, because they more easily fit between blocks that have already been allocated. That's what the comments are referring to as "heap fragmentation" -- when the program allocates a bunch of blocks and frees some of them, the freed blocks are interspersed among the blocks that haven't been freed. Allocating a large block could then fail, if none of the freed blocks is large enough for that block, while a bunch of smaller allocations could succeed, even though the amount of memory allocated to the smaller blocks is larger than the large block that failed.

Comment: so is there a workaround to constuct 1-d array?